# Como fazer uma infowindow com conteúdo diferente para cada markador em um loop

Tags: javascript, array, google-maps, loop, marker

Estou tentando fazer com que cada marcador desse loop possua uma infowindow com o conteúdo diferente, os arrays tem o mesmo tamanho e estão sendo pegos do banco, o problema é que ao em vez dele criar novas infowindow ele apenas substitui o conteúdo da antiga, ou seja, apesar de cada ponto abrir uma infowindow independente todas tem o mesmo conteúdo do último item do arrayNome[]

```
function AtivaMarkers(){
     for(i in arrayLat){

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: arrayNome[i]
    });
    var local = new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLat[i],arrayLng[i]);
  var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
title: arrayNome[i],
position: local,
icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png",
map: map
});        marcador.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,this);
    });
   markers.push(marcador);

 }

}
```

Gostaria de saber se ha maneiras de fazer uma infowindow diferente para cada marcador pelo loop, ja que a cada momento o tamanho dos arrays pode mudar então não posso me prender a um número fixo de infowindow.